# Creating an Asterisk Pyramid using user input

Tags: c++, input

How would I input 5 numbers and print each number as asterisks?

For example, if a user inputs 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 the output would look like this:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

This is what I have so far. I included one input for a number just to see if I was able to make it work, but it didn't.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int number;

cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
cin >> number;

for (count = 0; count <= 5; count++)
   {
    for (int asterisk = 0; asterisk < count; asterisk++)
         {
        cout << "*";
     }
     cout << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: Anyone can help answer this? :(

Comment: Welcome to SO! You have to tell us exactly what happens. "It doesn't work" isn't enough.

Comment: Your program doesn't even have a `main` function.  You cannot simply put code at the global scope in C++.  And you'd probably want to read the number inside the loop such that it is done five times.

Comment: You need a main function, also you did not define `count`.